# Какой пинг считается большим? 200-300, это много для сервинга в интернете?

Tags: хостинг, ping, icmp

Здравствуйте. Хостинг находится в США, ping из России согласно тестам 200-300ms. Следует ли переносить сайт на хостинг в Россию?

Сайт: Wordpress + форум bbPress 
Хостинг в США Namecheap

Выскажитесь те кто сидит в Москве и администрирует сервера в США.

Вопрос: является ли критичным пинг в 200-300 мс для пользователей из России? И следует ли вложить деньги и перенести сайт на хостинг в Москву?

Comment: Дополните вопрос. Что за сайт, какова цель, насколько критично время доступа?

Comment: обычно используют страны ЕС для хостинга, нидерланды всякие, что бы маски шоу у Вас дома не было

Comment: Не вижу каких-то критически требовательных к пингу ресурсов, считаю, что не обязательно переносить.

Comment: Технический вопрос или нет — на него всё равно нельзя ответить объективно и однозначно. Меня, может, и пинг в две секунды устроит, а соседу Васе Пупкину может 10 миллисекунд подавай. Или, быть может, из-за большого пинга пользователи не дожидаются загрузки вашего сайта и уходят. Или наоборот, более долгая загрузка задерживает их на подольше и тем самым повышает интерес к сайту. Хрен знает, в общем.

Comment: @andreymal можно, по крайней мере, достаточно объективно ситуации, в которых такой большой пинг будет критичной проблемой, и расписать способы борьбы с ним (кроме переноса)

Comment: @PashaPash это уже получается целая статья про пинги и «вопрос слишком общий».

Comment: @andreymal ниже есть пара ответов, которые вполне вписываются в формат SO, и не тянут на статью :)

Comment: @andreymal ну и опять же - мне кажется странным закрывать вопрос с формулировкой "нельзя дать объективный ответ", когда на него уже дано 3 вполне объективных (не начинающихся с "я так думаю") ответа.

Answer (score 5):

Согласно Google Pagespeed Insights время загрузки страницы должно быть в пределах до 0.2s (т.е. 200ms). Это учитывается при прохождении гуглоботом по вашему сайту при индексировании. Да и Яндекс тоже на этот параметр смотрит, т.к. время загрузки страницы влияет на "восприятие" вашего сайта. 
Однако, при работе сайта, когда вы отправляете запрос "получить страницу", эта страница должна еще и сформироваться, т.е. запрос должен быть обработан сервером - а это еще некоторое время. А у вас только на передачу запросов и получение ответа будет тратиться минимум 200-300ms. Так что время загрузки страницы будет куда больше. С другой стороны, гуглобот скорее всего будет этот сайт обходить с серверов в Америке (если регион сайта не указан "Россия"), Яндекс же - нет.

Следовательно, для продвижения - этот параметр будет очень критичен. С другой стороны, если вы не собираетесь продвигать этот сайт или же основная масса посетителей будет из Америки, тогда можно оставить там.

Если же сайт ориентирован на Россию - то тогда  хостинг желательно в России. Ну или хотя бы в Европе.

С другой стороны, [вступил в силу закон](http://minsvyaz.ru/ru/personaldata/), по которому если сайт хранит какую-либо информацию о Российских гражданах (а это имя, телефон и тому подобное, что как раз можно указать на любом форуме), то информация должна храниться на серверах, расположенных в РФ. Иначе может грозить крупный штраф. Такие штрафы обычно  ставятся не по факту самого нарушения, а за каждого человека, которого касается это нарушение. Т.е. пропорционально количеству человек, оставивших на сайте информацию о себе.

P.S.: [Данный закон](http://minsvyaz.ru/ru/personaldata/) касается только резидентов РФ, подробнее - в разделе "Трансграничность"

Comment: Что-то я не уверен про 200ms на загрузку страницы. Мне казалось, там секунда всегда была?

Comment: Неа. только что проверил. До этого сомневался 0.2 или 0.3, но теперь точно знаю что 0.2. Пишет "In our test, your server responded in 0.24 seconds. There are many factors that can slow down your server response time...."

Comment: Во-первых, какую-нибудь ссылку на описание можно? Во-вторых, "your server responded in" по формулировке не похоже на время полной загрузки страницы - это скорее либо задержка до начала ответа, либо до полного получения ответа на запрос без парсинга страницы и без загрузки и выполнения скриптов.

Comment: [Документация](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/Server) А server responded in - подразумевает время, прошедшее до получения ответа от сервера. В случае со статикой - это время примерно равно пингу, т.к. там ничего обрабатывать не нужно. А вот если страница динамическая - то это время уже получается сложением задержки до сервера и временем на обработку страницы

Comment: Так.. Не могу понять, что они замеряют: _"Время ответа сервера определяет, сколько занимает загрузка кода HTML для отображения страницы. **Задержка сети между Google и вашим сервером не учитывается.**"_ - так с какого момента и по какой должно быть 200ms?

Comment: Что-то я пропустил этот момент. Получается что гугл отправляет запрос на сайт, получает ответ "запрос получен, сейчас подожди, сгенерирую HTML" и вот время между получением этого ответа и началом получения HTML походу и учитывается. Значит пинг не учитывается. А учитывается время генерации HTML, т.е. Подключиться к БД, получить 2-3 записи и для каждой вывести все поля будет, к примеру 0.003мс, а вот Обработать 10000 записей и для каждой вывести все столбцы - уже скорее всего превысит порог в 0.2s

Comment: Раз вы затронули в ответе закон о персональных данных - добавьте, пожалуйста, в ответ выводы из раздела Трансграничность по вашей ссылке. Соблюдать законы РФ обязаны только резиденты РФ. Топикастер вполне может быть иностранцем (как я, например)

Answer (score 3):

Пусть страница у вашего пользователя начнёт загружаться через эти 200-300 мс. Если у вас сайт из статического HTML без картинок и https, то уменьшив [RTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_delay_time), вы увеличите скорость открытия сайта на идеальном соединении у идеального пользователя (забудем что [RTT ограничивает полосу пропускания TCP](https://blog.thousandeyes.com/a-very-simple-model-for-tcp-throughput/)).

Теперь вспомним что сайт у вас, скорее всего, динамический, на https, с кучей разного JS и картинок... Всё это вместе запросто может съесть секунду-другую на загрузку и подготовку к отображению вашей страницы в 
браузере. Гость сайта вашего не обязательно заходит с идеального соединения.

Это всё к тому что RTT не обязательно так важен, как может показаться. Оптимизация других частей сайта может принести много больше пользы, чем перенос сервера на более близкую к пользователю площадку.

От теоретических изысканий перейдём к практике. Рассмотрим сайт автора этого ответа, который живет на момент написания ответа на японском сервере с RTT из Европы в районе тех самых 200 мс. Сайт из статического HTML, значит у вас будет хуже. Для иллюстрации на момент тестирования на сервере был отключен OCSP stapling.

[image]

[WebPagetest](https://www.webpagetest.org/) показывает нам [на понятном графике](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/171011_N2_f1bdde87e02fc230eb2f35b4341179e4/2/details/#waterfall_view_step1) что DNS запросы заняли 327 мс, установка соединения предсказуемо заняла порядка одного RTT, а проверка SSL сертификата заняла целых две трети секунды. ([Включение OCSP stapling](https://www.alexeykopytko.com/2017/free-ssl-from-letsencrypt/#ocsp-stapling) сокращает время на проверку сертификата примерно в два раза.)

О чём это нам говорит? Не так страшен RTT как его малюют. Смотрите на что на самом деле тратится время при открытии страниц сайта. Очень может быть что уменьшение RTT в два раза не ускорит открытие страниц в те же два раза.

Answer (score 0):

Если аудитория сайта в России, стоит перенести в Европу.

Стоит ли переносить Россию - вопрос, конечно, очень спорный по понятным причинам (правило №1 из "9,5 правил ведения безопасного IT-бизнеса в России" гласит: Держите серверы за границей).
Если Вас устраивает Россия в качестве юрисдикции для ваших серверов - переносите в Россию.

Если аудитория и там, и там, желательно быть и там, и там.

P.S.: проблема с законом об обработке персональных данных, конечно же, не решится, если сервера переедут не в Россию. Но раз они и так в США, то, по всей видимости, это не проблема для автора вопроса.

Comment: Что это за понятные причины? Как тогда быть с законом об обработке персональных данных? А учитывая что есть форум - то есть и сбор персональных данных. Вот это понятная причина. Но это понятная причина за перенос в Россию. Если для вас "понятная причина" - это качество предоставляемых услуг, то я знаю как минимум одного хостера в СПБ, качество услуг которого на порядок выше многих зарубежных.

Comment: @VladimirNovopashin, http://minsvyaz.ru/ru/personaldata/, раздел Трансграничность. Если коротко - зависит от того, резидентом какой страны является топикастер. Если он не из России - то он никому в России ничего не должен

Comment: @PashaPash ну тут я скорее просто придрался к выражению "по понятным причинам", ибо по работе сталкивался с зарубежными и отечественными хостингами. Как у тех, так и у других есть аутсайдеры, а есть очень даже хорошие кандидаты. В ру зоне есть как минимум парочка привлекательных кандидатов. Тем более российские сервисы за ту же стоимость предоставляют более широкий функционал, а некоторые и более качественное обслуживание. Но за ссылку спасибо, вставлю её в ответ.